# Flutter : url_launcher exception

Tags: flutter

I am using url_launcher dependency to have a dial functionality on one of my icons; however, this works on Android but not IOS ?

Call launcher method would be:

```
   _launchcaller()  async
  {
    const url = '719-282-2224';

    if (await canLaunch(url))
    {
      await launch(url);
    }

    else{
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }

  }
```

Then I call that method on an onTap listener as below:

```
new GestureDetector(

             onTap: _launchcaller,

      child: new Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.blue, size: 50.0,),

    ),
```

Exception output:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
Could not launch tel:719-282-2224
#0      angryScreenState._launchcaller (file:///Users/ielbouyahyaouy/AndroidStudioProjects/app_firebase/flutter_app_books/lib/angryScreen.dart:103:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
#2      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:94:7)
#4      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
#5      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
#6      PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
#7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
#8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (packag<…>
```

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this? I'm in need of that. Thanks

Comment: You might be using ios simulator. try a physical device. It's a known issue with url_launcher for simulators

Answer (score 1):

For ios devices to understand the url as a phone number you need to strip out the dashes. You can do it this way. It should also be prefixed by tel://

```
url = 'tel://719-282-2224';
url = url.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'-'), ''); // remove dashes
```

Comment: It doesn't work with any of your suggestions, `tel:1234455` or `tel://123455`, threw the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
try {
       var cellphone = '719-282-2224';
       await launch('tel:$cellphone');
    }catch (e){
       throw 'Could not launch $e';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from API30 (Android 11), if you want to open a URL (dial number) in your flutter app then you should do the following configurations for using url_launcher:

1- For Android:

```
<manifest>

    <queries>

        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>

    </queries>

    <application>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

2- For iOS: Add the following to your info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```